# Re-arrange the Woocommerce checkout page layout

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I’d like to make some minor changes to the checkout page, mainly re-arranging sections and where they appear. For example, I might want to show the order review in a separate column as opposed to below the shipping/billing fields.

Ideally, if I could simply break down the different sections into shortcodes I could do this very easily with a page builder. For example, instead of having one master woocommerce_cart shortcode that is essentially the entire page, I’d like to have something a bit more granular, e.g. billing,shipping,review and payment shortcodes that I could freely place.

Is this possible, or is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: Would overriding the WooCommerce templates work?  https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

Comment: I was hoping to leverage the shortcodes because I could just use a page builder instead of editing HTML and PHP. Also makes styling each individual section easier.

Comment: I think then your best bet is to look at the WooCommerce templates and shortcodes and write your own into your theme's functions PHP.  As far as I know there aren't any overrides for WooCommerce shortcodes.

Comment: When I look at the templates, there's some sections with code like this: <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_billing' ); ?>
So I'm wondering if I could create a shortcode for each one of these do's and use that.

Comment: On another look, I can see why that might be complicated because all of those shortcodes would somehow need to be wrapped in a common <form>.
I'll keep this question open just in case someone has a fancy solution.

Comment: That's why I really think the best option would be to go with a template override.  Yeah, it's more complicated to have to write out all the HTML rather than use a page builder, but if you want to really have complete control, then you take complete control. Sorry.

Comment: Good point. Only downside with template override is I have to deal with responsive design, custom css, all that good stuff...I really like the idea of using a page builder for this but oh well.

Comment: It can be daunting but once you've done it a few times it starts to feel routine... ...I gave up on page builders a few years ago when one had a vulnerability and the devs pushed a new version, but to update to the new version, you had to rebuild every page because they changed the method of how their page builder content was written and stored.  The client's version had reach 'end of life' and once the vulnerability was exposed they were S.O.L.  It was a really eye opening experience.  :-(

Comment: Do you happen to have a 2 column layout php / css that you can share and that is responsive?